# view selected items from listview to next tab android

Tags: android, listview, tabs, selecteditem

I'm working on sales app. I have a listview that contains 10-15 items, which are selected through check button. I want that the selected items should display on next Tab. 
Any suggestion/help? How i should do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered using `Loaders` ? I never use this class myself but it seems to be what you are looking for. Here is the [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/loaders.html)

> Introduced in Android 3.0, loaders make it easy to asynchronously load
>   data in an activity or fragment. Loaders have these characteristics:
>
> - They are available to every Activity and Fragment.
> - They provide asynchronous loading of data.
> - They monitor the source of their data and deliver new results when the content changes.
> - They automatically reconnect to the last loader's cursor when being recreated after a
>     configuration change. Thus, they don't need to re-query their data.

You can also write into a file when you are selecting your items and read it when you display the selected items tab.

Comment: Loaders might not be useful because i want to check multiple items from the list then display the selected on next Tab

Answer (score 0):

Just save your selected item to some global storage and use `mTaHost.setCurrentTab(your_next_tab);` and then in that Tab fetch the selected item that you stored and display it.

Comment: any source or example would be more helpful!!

Comment: Ok use a setter getter class for storing the selected item or Application class for global acess and fetch on the next tab.

Comment: i've used getter setter too, but gives me force close error when i start checking the item

Comment: tab.layout.Product.onListItemClick(Product.java:128),android.app.ListActivity$2.onItemClick(ListActivity.java:321), android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587),android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) and other

Answer (score 0):

You could have a static public field in the class of the next tab that loads that specific item/items when that tab is reach and clears after it is used.

Comment: the list is populated from sqlite database...fields are not static

Comment: @user1296361, it has nothing to do with where the fields come from, just that you know what to display on the next tab.

Comment: @MeandWe, is storing it in global any better? I assume you mean in some sort of flat file that would need to be parsed.

Comment: @thantos you can store as gobally inside a class that extends Application using getter setter.